# Puppet variables best practice, generalise or specialise?

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to figure out which things should be in git within the puppet manifest and which should be in env vars like `FACTER_my_var` and use that in the manifest instead.

Scenario: you are deploying 3 php apps and you've already built all the layers up to the app in other manifests (base system, php extensions, users, etc), and all that's left is installing the correct app (from an apt repo) and creating a vhost.

I'm tempted to have something along the lines of:

```
apache::vhost { $::project_hostname:
    priority => '10',
    port => '80',
    docroot => $::project_document_root,
    logroot => "/var/log/apache2/${$::project_name}",
    serveradmin => 'example@example.com',
    require => Package[httpd],
    ssl => false,
    override => 'all',
    setenv => ["APP_KERNEL dev"]
}
```

This would run on each server, and the `FACTER_project_*` vars would be set on a per server basis. An obvious restriction of this would be that you can't run more than one app with this specific example.

Or would you rather have `project_x.pp`, `project_y.pp` which have hardcoded paths and names?

Comment: Where's the information about the project assigned to the server coming from?  If it's coming from the node, then it should be a fact; if it's coming from Puppet, then it should be in your manifests (or preferably, Hiera data).

Comment: Thanks Shane, it's coming from a fact (passed in via ec2 userdata)

Comment: Ok!  I'd say if there's enough in common, then definitely generalize your manifests to avoid repeating common elements.  Should also be doable to make it work for multiple projects being set up on a node, is that something that's likely to be needed in your deployment?

Comment: this is wrong ${$::project_name} it should ${::project_name}